# jquery validate, require field based on drop-down value

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a drop-down that lists types of reports the user can generate, once they select the type of report, it will display another drop-down, as seen in this screenshot. [image]

```
<select name="type_of_report" id="type_of_report">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="all_students">All students</option>
<option value="state">State</option>
<option value="sport_id">Sport</option>
<option value="major_id">Interest of Study</option>
<option value="graduation_year">High School Graduation Year</option>
<option value="recruitment_place_id">Where they heard about us</option>
</select>
```

If they select state, I'd want to require the state field.

In theory, this is what I'd like to do:

```
$("#type_of_report").live("change", function() {
 var report_selected = $("#type_of_report").val();
});

$("form").validate({
 rules: {

  if(report_selected != '') {
    report_selected: { required: true },
  }

  type_of_report: { required: true }
 }
});
```

Comment: I recently did a very complex dynamic form with lots of fields that the user could add.  These were newly created input elements, **not** hidden.  I simply added the class `required` to the new fields as they were created.

Comment: Thanks! I put in .addClass() and that did it.

Comment: Good deal.  Turned it into an answer.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did a very complex dynamic form with lots of fields that the user could add. These were newly created input elements, not hidden. I simply added the class `required`, using jQuery's `addClass`, to the new fields as they were created.

```
$("#myNewInput").addClass("required");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("form").submit(function() {
 var report_selected = $("#type_of_report").val();
 if(report_selected != '' && $('#other_select').val() == '') {
    alert('selected a report, but not the 2nd one');
    return false;
 }
 return true;
});
```

Comment: Kind of, looking to work it with the jquery validate plugin, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realize! Then you were probably right with the bind change, but maybe you have to add/remove the rule when the 1st select value changes? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules